# like button for my website isn't using correct information

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-like, scrape

I am designing a blog using blogger for a fundraiser my team is doing.  I have purchased a domain through godaddy "solematesforlife.org" which i have aimed at my blog "solemateswalk.blogspot.com".

When i first installed the like button i didn't realize i needed to specify the resources used on facebook.  When i realized what i had done i installed the appropriate meta tags in my header, and tried to use the debug tool to re-scrape the blog.

The problem that im having is that when i run my URL through debug it picks up on the new "image, url, description and title", but doesn't bother updating the "object properties" which it uses when people click my like button.

This is a big problem because if the new image isn't replaced and the description added, i would rather just remove the like link all together..

I have read and read and read on this subject, and think i have a pretty good grasp on how this is supposed to work, however i cannot claim that i am a java programmer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: SOLUTION:  When using a domain forwarding service such as Go Daddy, you MUST use the URL of the "actual" site.  

IE: my Go Daddy domain name was 'solematesforlife.org' and my actual webpage URL was 'http://www.solemateswalk.blogspot.com'

1)Change your Meta tag URL to your 'actual url'
2)Refresh your real url using 'facebook lint'
3)Change your 'facebook like' button url to your 'actual url'

Unfortunately this doesn't allow you to use your registered domain name (from go daddy), but you will at least be able to specify the data used to represent yourself on people's facebook posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I lint solemateswalk.blogspot.com I get errors, fix that redirect loop and it should be a lot better.

> **URL Follow Failed**:    There was an error in fetching the object at URL
> 'http://solemateswalk.blogspot.com/', or one of the the URLs specified
> via a redirect or the 'og:url' property including one of
> http://www.solematesforlife.org.
>
> **Circular Redirect**:    Circular redirect
> path detected (see Redirect Path section for details).
>
> **Error Scraping Redirect**:  Bad Response Code (redirect)

Comment: In the developers page (where you copied from) it says "see redirect path section for details".  The problem is that ive looked and looked and haven't been able to find said "redirect path section"..

I believe that error is coming because when you go to solematesforlife.org godaddy automatically forwards you to blogspot..  I think its asking for meta tags from both URLs; problem being that there isn't anywhere i can put meta tags for the go daddy domain..

Comment: No, I think your `og:url` meta tag located in your blogspot is pointing to http://www.solematesforlife.org, which it should not be.  It should have your blogspot url in it instead, especially since you've asked GoDaddy redirect to blogspot when they come to your url.

Comment: Your awesome!  There seems to be a gap in the documentation for the like button.  Ill add another answer at the bottom outlining the solution to my problem, cause i looked long and hard to find this information.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding Open Graph metatags to your page.

In first order, Facebook Like and Share looks to these tags first to determine the content to display on Facebook from your page.

I.E

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Title">
<meta property="og:type" content="">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.YourURL.com">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.YourSite.com/image.jpg">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name">
<meta property="og:description" content="Enter a description that will attract Facebook users. Use no more than 255 characters.">
```

this is a decent article on the subject:

http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

Here is a Open Graph meta-tag generator you can use:

http://www.metataggenerator.org/open-graph-meta-tags/

Comment: As i said in my question, i already added those meta tags.  When i go to debug, it rescrapes the page and finds the meta tags and lists them, but doesn't update any of the information it actually uses

Comment: ah, it's probably caching the old version of the page. Try changing the filename or adding a query string or #sometext to the end of the URL. See if that helps.